# Python Tkinter Treeview search all entries

Tags: python, python-3.x, search, tkinter, treeview

I use a treeview to show all items a folder contains.

I create all entries with this function:

```
def SUBS(path, parent):    
    for p in os.listdir(path):
        abspath = os.path.join(path, p)
        parent_element = tree.insert(parent, 'end', text=p, open=True)
        if os.path.isdir(abspath):
            SUBS(abspath, parent_element)
```

and now i want to search through it with this function:

```
def search(event, item=''): 
    children = tree.get_children(item)
    for child in children:
        text = tree.item(child, 'text')
        if text.startswith(entry.get()):
            tree.selection_set(child)
```

The Problem is that the search function only search through the first "nodes". Not all. So how do i search throug the children of a child? And how are they called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use recursion like in your SUBS function ?

```
def search(event, item=''): 
    children = tree.get_children(item)
    for child in children:
        text = tree.item(child, 'text')
        if text.startswith(entry.get()):
            tree.selection_set(child)
        search(None, item=child) # Use the function for all the children, their children, and so on..
```

Comment: I tried that before but i failed to use that for the child of a child. Sorry if this is ultimate beginner but can you please Show me how to do that?

Comment: I got it! Thanks for your help!